# Есть ли смысл передавать указатель по ссылке в функцию?

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, ссылки, передача-параметров

К примеру есть следующий код:

```
#include <cassert>

class MyClass {
  int m_Data;
public:
  MyClass(int initVal) : m_Data(initVal) {}
  void SetData(int data) { m_Data = data; }
  int GetData() { return m_Data; }
};

// Передача по указателю:
void MyFunctionPtr(MyClass* arg) {
  arg->SetData(arg->GetData() * arg->GetData());
}

// Передача указателя по ссылке:
void MyFunctionPtrRef(MyClass*& arg) {
  arg->SetData(arg->GetData() * arg->GetData());
}

// Передача по ссылке:
void MyFunctionRef(MyClass& arg) {
  arg.SetData(arg.GetData() * arg.GetData());
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  MyClass* my = new MyClass(2);

  MyFunctionPtr(my);
  assert(my->GetData() == 4);

  MyFunctionPtrRef(my);
  assert(my->GetData() == 16);

  MyFunctionRef(*my);
  assert(my->GetData() == 256);

  delete my;
  return 0;
}
```

Является ли передача указателя по ссылке `MyClass*& arg` менее затратной, чем передача указателя по значению `MyClass* arg`? За счет того, что при передаче по ссылке не происходит копирования указателя. Какой из трех способов наиболее быстрый:

- передача указателя по значению;
- передача указателя по ссылке;
- передача по ссылке.

Есть ли вообще смысл передавать указатель по ссылке, если мы не собираемся менять адрес памяти, который хранит указатель?

Comment: `Какой из трех способов наиболее быстрый:` - мне кажется, что они примерно одинаковые. Передача по ссылке примитивных типов (таких как числа и указатели) вроде бы даже медленее чем передача по значению (зависит от платформы, я не очень разбираюсь, но там на одной платформе передача параметров через регистры, на других нет).
`Есть ли вообще смысл передавать указатель по ссылке, если мы не собираемся менять адрес памяти, который хранит указатель?` - мне кажется нет смысла. Пока Вы не передаёте сложные (пользовательские) типы по значению, всё у Вас условно хорошо и быстро работает

Comment: Существенной разницы точно нет. Максимум пара тройка асемблеровских операций. При этом, непонятно в чью пользу. В таких случаях нужно отдавать преимущество более читабельному коду. `MyClass*&` повергнет в шок читающего ваш код программиста. Так никто не пишет. Кажется, что вы хотите менять указатель, а это странно. Не стоит так делать. `MyClass& arg` и `MyClass* arg` записи в принципе равносильны и обе используются.

Answer (score 1):

В этом нет никакого смысла. Ссылки и указатели являются тонкой абстракцией над адресами*, используемыми в ассемблере. Поэтому, передавая ссылку на указатель, Вы, в сущности, передаёте указатель на указатель, вводя ненужный уровень косвенности. Т.е. если с передачей указателя по значению Вы напрямую обращаетесь к объекту, куда он указывает (один уровень косвенности), то используя ссылку, Вам сначала нужно обратиться по ссылке, чтобы извлечь указатель, чтобы извлечь объект, на который он указывает (два уровня косвенности).

---

(*) Конечно, это всё не по стандарту и прочее и прочее, но для примерного понимания разницы этого должно быть достаточно.

Answer (score 0):

Имеет смысл, если использовать указатель вместо итератора в функции, например

```
void add(int*& it, int add){
    *it += add;it++;
}

int main(){
  int a[2] = {1,2};
  int* b = a;
  add(b, *b);
  add(b, *b);
  cout<<a[0]<<','<<a[1]; //2,4
}
```